# How do I use the current user to create a model with pickle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I have just set up Pickle with Factory girl like this (features/support/pickle.rb):

```
Pickle.configure do |config|
   config.adapters = [:factory_girl]
   config.map 'I', 'myself', 'me', 'my', :to => 'user: "me"'
end
```

And I now want to start a cucumber scenario like this:

```
Given a journal exists with user: me
```

So that it creates an instance of the journal model with the current user as the user_id, but I get this error:

```
Pickle::Session::ModelNotKnownError: The model: 'user: "me"' is not known in this
scenario.  Use #create_model to create, or #find_model to find, and store a reference 
in this scenario.
```

How do I get Pickle to match 'me' to current_user? The hint in the error message doesn't tell me how or where to store it.

n.b. The login step I have made already stores the current user in `@me`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's OK - I found it. Add this to the 'I am logged in' step:

```
store_model('user', 'me', @me) # Where @me is the logged in user record
```